# Compare two text files to check occurrence of a substring

Tags: python-2.7

I have two text files with data as:
file1:

```
0
1
2
0/0/0/2
0/1/1/2
```

and file2:

```
Lo0
Lo1
Te0/0/0/2
Te0/0/1/4
Te0/1/1/2
```

I want to compare file1 and file2 such that if i`th`element of file1 occurs in corresponding i `th`element in file2, output them in a separate file, else check for occurrence of file1 in next element of file2. Basically, here, the final output should be:

```
Lo0                 #as 0 occurs here
Lo1                 #as 1 occurs here
Te0/0/0/2           #as 0/0/0/2 occurs here
Te0/1/1/2           #as 0/1/1/2 occurs here
```

Please help me to proceed! I have tried:

```
for i1 in range(len(file2)):
    for i2 in range(len(file1)):
        if file1[i2]==file2[i1]:
             desc.write(file1[i2])
             desc.write(file2[i1+1])
             desc.write('\n')
```

Basically, I want to write the next element of a file which has file2 as its sub-contents if file2 has matching strings in file1 else write "NotSame".

Comment: Are the files guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: @Arashsoft, I have added my trial. Please let me know how to proceed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have much to go on, but if the files are the same length then this should work.

```
f1 = open('file1.txt').readlines()
f2 = open('file2.txt').readlines()
output = open('output.txt', 'w')

for i in xrange(len(f1)):
   if f1[i] in f2[i]:
      output.write(f2[i])
```

Comment: the files aren't of the same length

Comment: Well, if file2 is longer than file1 in the case above, it should still work, if not, you'll need to change the loop to `for i in xrange(len(f2)):`

Comment: It's not working, the code is aborted as soon as it finds one dis-similar element, i.e 0/0/1/4 in this case.

Comment: @alisha whoops, forgot to add open before the `('output.txt', 'w')`. It was just calling it as a tuple instead of a file stream. Should work now.

Comment: f2 is smaller than f1, so it will show out of index if I run till the length of f1.

Comment: @alisha Thats what I mentioned in my second comment, you'll need to switch the loop to `for i in xrange(len(f2)):`